# Show that this conversion between $\Phi$ and erf(z) holds for all z

Tags: normal-distribution, error-function

I am trying to wrap my head around the connections between the standard Normal distribution and the error function. I could use some help working through the following problem.

Show that the following conversion between $\Phi$ and erf holds for all z:

$\Phi(z) = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}erf(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})$

The second part of this question asks to show that erf is an odd function. I am new to the normal distribution and don't really know where to start. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Try drawing out the regions on which we're integrating $e^{-z^2 /2}$. For $\Phi$ it is from $-\infty$ to $z$. For erf($\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}$) it is from 0 to $z$. The difference is the integral from $-\infty$ to 0, or $\Phi(0)$.